# Incomplete file using RandomAccessFile in java

Tags: java, file, corruption

I made a small program to download data and write it to a file.

Here is the code:

```java
public void run()
{

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int bytes_read;

    URLConnection urlc = null;
    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    InputStream i = null;


    try
    {
         raf = new RandomAccessFile("file1", "rw");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
         urlc =  new URL(link).openConnection();
         i = urlc.getInputStream();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    while(canDownload())
    {
        try
        {
            bytes_read = i.read(bytes);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if(bytes_read != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                raf.write(bytes, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                i.close();
                raf.close();
                return;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I download big files, I get few bytes missing in the end of the file.
I tried to change the byte array size to 2K, and the problem was solved. But when I downloaded a bigger file (500 MB) , I got few bytes missing again.
I said "Ok, let's try with 4K size". And I changed the byte array size to 4K. It worked!
Nice, but then I downloaded a 4 GB file, I got bytes missing in the end again!
I said "Cool, let's try with 8K size". And then I changed the byte array size to 8K. Worked.

My first question is: Why this happens? (when I change buffer size, the file doesn't get corrupted).

Ok, in theory, the file corrupted problem can be solved changing the byte array size to bigger values.
But there's another problem: how can I measure the download speed (in one second interval) with big byte array sizes?

For example: Let's say that my download speed is 2 KB/s. And the byte array size is 4 K. 
My second question is: How can I measure the speed (in one second interval) if the thread will have to wait the byte array to be full? My answer should be: change the byte array size to a smaller value. But the file will get corrupted xD.

After trying to solve the problem by myself, I spent 2 days searching over the internet for a solution. And nothing.

Please, can you guys answer my two questions? Thanks =D

**Edit**

Code for canDownload():

```java
synchronized private boolean canDownload()
{
    return can_download;
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `canDownload()`

Comment: I added to the question text.

Comment: Let's say your file size is 300*2k+35 bytes, are you missing the last 35 bytes?

Comment: No. Yesterday I downloaded the same file twice, with the same byte array size. One got corrupted and the other didn't. I tried to download a very small file (less than 1KB) with byte array size = 8k, and it didn't get corrupted.

Comment: You showed the code but you didn't answer the real question. When is `can_download` set to false? It appears that it is being cleared prematurely.

Comment: can_download is not used yet. It will be used for pause/resume options.

Comment: Have you tried making sure you are writing to a fresh file each time? Try deleting the first file before writing to it again from a different link.

Comment: I've already tried that. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to use a proven library such as [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) instead of trying to roll your own code. For your particular problem, take a look at the [copyURLToFile(URL, File)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29) method.

Comment: I'm going to add functionality to my program (pause, resume, etc). And I need to measure the download speed. This a download manager prototype.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Change the RandomAccessFile to a FileOutputStream.
2. Get rid of `canDownload()`, whatever it's for, and set a read timeout on the connection instead.
3. Simplify the copy loop to this:

   while ((bytes_read = i.read(bytes)) > 0)
   {
     out.write(bytes, 0, bytes_read);
   }
   out.close();
   i.close();

with all the exception handling *outside* this loop.

Comment: I want to add functionality to my program (like pausing and resuming downloads). And I need RandomAccessFile for that.
canDownload() is useless now, but soon it will be used to control user commands to the download.
What's the problem with exception handling inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the problem is that you closed the underlying InputStream while the RandomAccessFile still had data in its write buffers. This will be why you are occasionally missing the last few bytes of data.

The race condition is between the JVM flushing the final write, and your call to i.close().

Removing the i.close() should fix the problem; it isn't necessary as the raf.close() closes the underlying stream anyway, but this way you give the RAF a chance to flush any outstanding buffers before it does so.

Comment: But if I remove `i.close()`, the connection will not be closed, and I want to close that connection after the download end.
I didn't understand the relationship between raf.write() and i.close(). 
For me, what matters is the byte buffer size (please look at my two questions).

Comment: As I said, raf.close() closes the underlying stream. Your buffer size is completely irrelevant to your problem. What matters is that you are not properly flushing java.io's buffers before closing the stream/exiting the vm. The obvious culprit is the extraneous i.close(). As far as measuring the speed is concerned, you have the aggregate bytes read, and System.getCurrentTimeMillis() will tell you how long you have been downloading. Of course, @Anthony-accioly is right, if you had used org.apache.commons.io.input.CountingInputStream you would be finished already.

Comment: @Recurse I don't think you are correct. There is no relation between the `InputStream i` and the `RandomAccessFile raf`; where do you see that? `i.close()` is not extraneous at all. In addition, RandomAccessFile does not have a buffer so there is nothing to flush after calling `raf.write()`.

Comment: That's my point. `raf` and `i` are not related. They only use the same byte array.
And yes, the buffer size is relevant, because if I change it to a higher value, the file won't get corrupted. And as I said, I need to deal with the opened connection, I can't just delete `i.close()`.

Comment: @Recurse, How can I use `org.apache.commons.io.input.CountingInputStream` to measure the speed within 1 second interval, with a very low download speed (less than 1KB/s)? I'll have to wait until the byte array get filled with the bytes downloaded to get the amount of bytes downloaded? If yes, the speed problem is still unsolved.

Comment: I found a way to measure the speed. I'll use `i.read()` instead of `i.read(bytes)`; so, I'll make a loop to read byte by byte, and then I can create a variable to store the bytes read. Now the problem is the `RandomAccessFile`; how can I deal with the byte array size?